# Agrandar el grafico en pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

necesito saber si puedo agrandar de alguna manera el grafico para que los nombres de abajo puedan ser legibles.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Si es posible, para eso debes utilizar el argumento `figsize`

```
df_clima.plot.scatter(x='Lugar', y='Lluvia', figsize=(10,15))
```

El primer valor, en este caso 10, es el ancho y el segundo valor, en este caso 15, es el alto de la gráfica

O lo que podrías hacer es utilizar el argumento `rot` para rotar las etiquetas del eje "x" y que sean legibles, por ejemplo:

```
df_clima.plot.scatter(x='Lugar', y='Lluvia', figsize=(10,15), rot=45)
```